# jQuery length property error

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery, and I'm trying to invoke this line:

```
mobilePhoneSuffix.val().length < 7
```

I'm getting an error on that line.

Here's where I set `var mobilePhoneSuffix`:

```
var mobilePhoneSuffix = $('#mobilePhoneSuffix');
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Does the id mobilePhoneSuffix exist? Try without upper case

Comment: Is `#mobilePhoneSuffix` an input or other form field?

Comment: Yes, this line: mobilePhoneSuffix.val().length == 0 working ok

Comment: Please post more code, including the HTML. You also have to have it wrapped in `document.ready()`.

Comment: Try `<= 6` instead of `< 7` and see if that makes a difference...

Comment: As a side note - when replying to comments, address specific users with `@` for example @Purmou will address that user letting him know you posted a comment..

Comment: @lolo just print the value returned by val()... that's very likely to be the problem.... considering you actually have an element with the given id... and as @(Shadow Wizard) pointed out, you run this inside the ready() function.... and also make sure you call val() only AFTER adding the element to the DOM.

Comment: besides the error message please post the html

Comment: @lolo: from your comment " mobilePhoneSuffix.val().length == 0 working ok "  , it seems that error is in the statements inside the condition which are executed when `mobilePhoneSuffix.val().length < 7` makes the condition true. Please post complete if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem.
This scirpt should be between

```
<!-- -->
```

otherwise the html think that the argument < is an html open tag.